# Get all possible matches in a regex match (In Java)?

Tags: java, regex, string

I am using a regex to match few possible values in a string that coming with my objects, there I need to get all possible values that are matching from my string as below,

If my string value is `"This is the code ABC : xyz use for something"`.

Here is my code that I am using to extract matchers,

```
String my_regex = "(ABC|ABC :).*";

List <String> matchers = Pattern.compile(my_regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
                                .matcher(my_string)
                                .results()
                                .map(MatchResult::group)
                                .collect(Collection.toList());
```

I am expecting the 2 list items as the output > {"ABC", "ABC :"}, But I am only getting one. Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There could be situation that my string value coming like `"This is the code ABC xyz use for something"`. In that case I have to have the `"ABC"` only filter as well.

Comment: This code finds the groups match your pattern "(ABC|ABC :).*", and your string has only one matched group "ABC : xyz...", so it only has one item in list.

Comment: With your regex, all possible matches as you mentioned should be: "ABC", "ABC :", "ABC : ", "ABC : x", ... so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe just isn't how regex engines work. They do not find all possible variant search results; they simply consume and give you all results, moving forward. In other words, had you written:

```
String my_regex = "(ABC|ABC :)"; // note, get rid of the .*
String myString = "This is the code ABC : xyz use for something ABC again";
```

Then you'd get 2 results back - `ABC :` and `ABC`.

Yes, the regex could just as easily match just the `ABC` part instead of the `ABC :` part and it would still be valid. However, regexp matching is by default 'greedy' - it will match as much as it can. For some operators (specifically, `*` and `+`) you can use the non-greedy variants: `*?` and `+?` which will match as little as possible.

In other words, given:

```
String regex = "(a*?)(a+)";
String myString = "aaaaa";
```

Then group 1 would match 0 `a` (that's the shortest string that can match `(a*?)` whilst still being able to match the entire regex to the input), and group 2 would be `aaaaa`.

If, on the other hand, you wrote `(a*)(a+)`, then group 1 would be `aaaa` and group 2 would be `a`. It is not possible to ask the regexp engine to provide for you the combinatory explosion, with every possible length of 'a' - which appears to be what you want. The regexp API that ships with java does not have any option to do this, nor does any other regexp API I know of, so you'd have to write that yourself, perhaps. I admit I haven't scoured the web for every possible alternate regex engine impl for java, there are a bunch of third party libraries, perhaps one of them can do it.

NB: I said at the start: Get rid of the .*. That's because otherwise it's still just the one match: `ABC : xyz use for something ABC again` is the longest possible match and given that regex engines are greedy, that's what you will get: It is a valid 'interpretation' of your string (1 match), consuming the most - that's how it works.

NB2: Greediness can never change whether a regex even matches or not. It just changes which of the input is assigned to which group, and when `find()`ing more than once (which `.results()` does - it `find()`s until no more matches are found - which matches you get.

Comment: Thank you so much for this valuable explanation. I learnt a lot. Thanks!